# Assembly login program always returns incorrect password

Tags: assembly, authentication, x86, compare

I'm working on an assembly program that will take user input and check it against variable, but for some reason this code will always say that the password was input incorrectly. Just to note, I didn't include the code for some of the calls made, but I am certain that they do work, as I've used them perfectly in many other examples. Basically, I'm need to know why this refuses to rocognize that my input and the string match. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
start:
mov ax, login_input
mov bx, login_message
call os_input_dialog     ;opens a dialog box that shows the string login_message,
                                  ;then it takes user input andd stores it in ax

mov si, login_input      
mov di, password
cmp si, di                    ;compares input against the password
je app_selector            ;if equal, jump to the next part of code

jmp start                     ;otherwise try again


login_input               times 12 db 0
login_message            db 'Password: '
password                    db 'root'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not even comparing the strings, you're comparing the *base addresses* of the strings, which will never be equal. You need to compare each element of each string to know whether they are equal or not.